# PDFJS.PDFLinkService is not a function

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am following a tutorial for adding the search function inside my pdf reader, I followed all the steps correctly by importing the javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdfviewer/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdfviewer/viewer.js"></script>
```

then used the following code

```
PDFJS.workerSrc = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdfviewer/pdf.worker.js";         
PDFJS.disableStream = true;
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
var pdfLinkService = new PDFJS.PDFLinkService();
var pdfViewer = new PDFJS.PDFViewerApplication({
    container: document.getElementById("div-viewer"),
    linkService: pdfLinkService
});
pdfLinkService.setViewer(pdfViewer);
var pdfFindController = new PDFJS.PDFFindController({
    pdfViewer: pdfViewer
});
pdfViewer.setFindController(pdfFindController);
```

It seems to work for all but I am getting the following error message:

> "PDFJS.PDFLinkService is not a function"

and

> "pdfViewer is not defined".

Tried to google but nobody is getting my error message, the code is the one used on mozilla github.

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: PDFViewerApplication is not a class and cannot be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was about a wrong lib in the project, I didn't need viewer.js but pdf_viewer.js, now I don't have any problem declaring a new instace of the class PDFLinkService but when declaring

```
var pdfViewer = new PDFJS.PDFViewerApplication({
container: document.getElementById("div-viewer"),
linkService: pdfLinkService
```

});

I get this error:

```
this.viewer is null
```

Looks like the pdf_viewer.js cannot correctly create the instance of this class although nothing seems weird in the code, am I missing some lib or something? I am looking on internet but it looks like I have all the correct references.

Comment: see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because PDFLinkService() is not a function of PDFjsLib, you need to call that from PdfJsViewer.

Try this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/web/pdf_viewer.js"></script>

const PdfJsViewer = window['pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer'];
 const pdfLinkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService({
  eventBus,
});
```

Rest you can check here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.js